# recursive std::remove_pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having difficulty with types, such as:

```
T******************************************
```

Should `std::remove_pointer` be able to handle such types at all (I don't think so)? How to remove all the `*`? If there is an ampersand `&` or two added at the end, does there exist a metafunction from the `C++11` standard to strip such a type down to `T` without using both the `std::remove_reference` and `std::remove_pointer` metafunctions?

Comment: Why would this exist in the standard? How often is it useful to do this transformation? I can't think when it would ever be useful, `T*` and `T**********` have very little in common, they don't point to the same type so why is it useful to extract `T` from them both?

Comment: @JonathanWakely I needed this to instantiate T, even if `T**********` was provided. I don't know why it would exist in the standard, but if it had, I would have used the metafunction from the standard.

Comment: just had a need for it, to perform reflection on a user-provided type which may be T, T* or T** (user can pass an audio sample, audio channel, or array of audio channels and it should be filled appropriately, but the type of T is needed at some point)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not too hard to write a meta-function that will return return the base type no matter how many `*`s and `&`s you have.

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_all_ref_ptr { typedef T type; };

template <typename T>
struct remove_all_ref_ptr<T *> : public remove_all_ref_ptr<T> { };

template <typename T>
struct remove_all_ref_ptr<T * const> : public remove_all_ref_ptr<T> { };

template <typename T>
struct remove_all_ref_ptr<T * volatile> : public remove_all_ref_ptr<T> { };

template <typename T>
struct remove_all_ref_ptr<T * const volatile> : public remove_all_ref_ptr<T> { };

template <typename T>
struct remove_all_ref_ptr<T &> : public remove_all_ref_ptr<T> { };

template <typename T>
struct remove_all_ref_ptr<T &&> : public remove_all_ref_ptr<T> { };
```

And `::std::remove_pointer` can handle types like that just fine. It just lops off a single `*`.

The little meta-function I just wrote will run into the recursion depth limit eventually. But you'll likely have to put on more than a hundred `*`s to make that happen.

Here is how you might use it in conjunction with a standard library meta-function to remove the const and volatile qualifiers as well:

```
 #include <type_traits>

 template <typename T>
 struct base_type : public ::std::remove_cv<typename remove_all_ref_ptr<T>::type> { };
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `typedef` be `public` or the `class` made into `struct`?

Comment: @user1095108: You're right. My compiler (g++ 4.7.2) has failed me. :-)

Comment: I suppose this metafunction could easily be improved to strip `cv` also?

Comment: @user1095108: Yes. I should probably have handled the `* const` case in there actually. I think that edit should do it.

Comment: @user1095108: I added something to remove const and volatile qualifiers as well. Of course, one problem this does not handle is unwrapping smart pointer types into the pointed-to type.