# Create is_primitive or is_inheritable template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std

I would like to create a template that checks if a class type is a primitive or not (int, char, float, float***, ect...).  The reason for this is to prevent another template from trying to extend primitives and cause a compile-time error.  So far I have something along the lines of:

```
#include <typeinfo>
template<typename T>
struct is_primitive{
   const static bool value=std::is_fundamental<T>::value;
};
```

Obviously this just forwards the result from is_fundamental right now.  I'd like to add remove_pointer, remove_reference, ect... to strip all of those extra modifiers of the input class.  **What are all the removals necessary to make T as bare as possible?**

Alternatively, a solution like the following would be equally outstanding:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_inheritable{
   const static bool value=???;
};
```

But I'm pretty sure the set of uninheritable classes equals the set of primitive classes.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`is_fundamental`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental). Note that (as written in your question), a class type is never primitive (fundamental), as a class type is always introduced via either `class` or `struct`.

Comment: Wow I don't know why I missed that, but I don't think it catches all of the references, pointer parts, and other stuff that I might not know about (still fairly new to the real C++ world).  I'll update my question with is_fundamental.

Comment: The "baring" of `T` is usually called `Unqualified<T>`, and it's enough to chain `RemoveCv<RemoveReference<T>>` - references can't be cv-qualified, so they must be at top-level. You can't have references to references or pointers to references, so again, they must be at top-level. After that, just strip the cv-qualificaiton. (Cv-qualified means const- and/or volatile-qualified.)

Comment: I think the only problem left is class**...** instances.  Found this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951868/recursive-stdremove-pointer.  So I think that's everything...  Let me double check.

Comment: Can you perhaps be more concrete about why you need this in the first place? Might be a simpler approach.

Comment: I had a test question that asked me to make a bool function template to determine if a class had virtual functions or not.  My answer was to extend the class, add a virtual function, and test whether the sizeof() the derived and base class changed due to an addition of a virtual function table pointer.  My method fails to compile if you try to test  primitives, references, pointers, ect...

Comment: @Aggieboy: Classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/164572). Your solution is not a good solution, because it certainly does not solve the problem. Even ignoring the fact that you're assuming that vtable pointers exist (an implementation detail that C++ does not require), I can easily break your code by passing it an empty class on some C++ compilers. An empty class must have a size, but the empty-base-optimization means that derived classes can be the same size as the base, even with the extra vtable pointer.

Comment: Hmm I do see how this is an XY problem, however I think something like this is still useful when you have a class that extends a template type isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want `std::is_class<T>`.  One can only inherit from class types. This is a diagram that depicts the C++11 type classification traits: [Here http://howardhinnant.github.io/TypeHiearchy.pdf](http://howardhinnant.github.io/TypeHiearchy.pdf)

http://howardhinnant.github.io/TypeHiearchy.pdf

Comment: This is great. Has anything changed since 2007 that would cause this to be out of date? (EDIT: For example, `is_signed` split is missing; purposeful, oversight, or out of date?)

Comment: @GManNickG: I haven't double checked, but I think no.  Note though that this diagram only models 20.9.4.1 Primary type categories and 20.9.4.2 Composite type traits.  The former describes all "leaf" types in 3.9 Types, and the latter describes the non-leaf types in this tree.  `is_signed`, along with many other traits enters in 20.9.4.3 Type properties, none of which are represented in this diagram.  An intended invariant is that every type in C++ fits into exactly one of the Primary Type Categories (leafs in the above diagram).

Comment: Wow this answers a lot more questions I had in addition to the OP lol.  I picked this one because it's so concise and informative.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb:  This part of the classification is structured after 3.9.2 Compound types [basic.compound].  There's a leaf for each bullet in p1.  And being able to distinguish between classes and unions sure comes in handy.  E.g. you can't implement `std::throw_with_nested` without it.  We could have made `is_class` the "or" of `is_union` and `is_non_union_class`, but that just seemed awkward and pedantic to the point of distraction.

Comment: @HowardHinnant hmm, I see.

Comment: @HowardHinnant What exactly does "function" refer to on the very right?  Is it a function pointer, or does it just mean a global function?  It certainly doesn't mean std::function, as that would be a class.

Comment: @TrevorHickey:  The `F` in `typedef void F();` is a function.  `std::is_function<F>::value` is true.  `std::is_pointer<F>::value` is false.  The `FP` in `typedef void (*FP)();` is a pointer to a function.  `std::is_function<FP>::value` is false.  `std::is_pointer<FP>::value` is true.  `std::is_function<std::remove_pointer<FP>::type>::value` is true.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try to focus on detecting the properties of a type that are required to be inheritable *in your case* instead of thinking about detecting those types that are not. With any luck, your class needs additional properties from your base class that can be checked because your derived class will need to call at least one constructor of the base class.

Try using [`is_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) or some related type trait:

```
// check that T::T(std::string,int); exists:
std::is_constructible< T, std::string, int >::value

// or these direct traits for the usual suspects...
std::is_default_constructible< T >::value
std::is_copy_constructible< T >::value
std::is_move_constructible< T >::value
```

For your other question, if it is still relevant after the above, check out [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) and combine it with other traits to strip the type as needed:

```
template< typename T, typename = void >
struct strip
{
     typedef T type;
};

template< typename T >
struct strip< T, typename std::enable_if<
  !std::is_same< typename std::decay< T >::type, T >::value
>::type >
    : strip< typename std::decay< T >::type >
{
};

template< typename T >
struct strip< T, typename std::enable_if<
  std::rank< T >::value != 0
>::type >
    : strip< typename std::remove_all_extents< T >::type >
{
};

template< typename T >
struct strip< T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_pointer< T >::value >::type >
    : strip< typename std::remove_pointer< T >::type >
{
};

typedef const int*(&Test)[42];
static_assert( std::is_same< typename strip< Test >::type, int >::value, "" );
```

but of couse you need to figure out what exactly is appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_all { typedef typename std::remove_cv<T>::type type; };
template <typename T>
struct remove_all<T*> { typedef typename remove_all<T>::type type; };
template <typename T>
struct remove_all<T&> { typedef typename remove_all<T>::type type; };
template <typename T>
struct remove_all<T&&> { typedef typename remove_all<T>::type type; };

template<typename T>
struct is_primitive{
    typedef typename remove_all<T>::type TF;
    const static bool value=std::is_fundamental<TF>::value;
};
```

remove_all struct discussion found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951868/recursive-stdremove-pointer).

Comment: `std::cout << std::is_same< remove_all< int*const >::type, int* >::value` --  your `remove_all` is misleadingly named?

Comment: It's supposed to remove all pointer and reference attributes, however I was a little lazy with cvs like const.  So it should turn int*const -> int, however I think the postfix const screws it up